# Reading data from a Binary/Random Access File

Tags: c++, qt, binaryfiles, random-access

I have a file in binary format having a large amount of data.

If I have knowledge of the file structure, how do I read information from the binary file, and populate a record of these structures?

The data is complex.

I'd like to do it with Qt, but I would do it in C++ as well, if required.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Oh, sorry if it's not very clear. I wanted to know how to read information from a binary file, using Qt..and populate a record I have. Do i need a QByteArray as an intermediate, or can I populate my record structure directly?

Comment: You should *edit* your post to make it a question. Tip: If it doesn't have a question mark in it, it should probably go on a blog rather than SO.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, I realized it. I marked it as a question.

Comment: Qt is not a programming language, you can't do that in Qt, you can with Qt.

Comment: OK..How do I do that with Qt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2604/fall00/binio.html would be help for you. I've learned from there. (hint always cast your data as(char*) ).

Answer (score 0):

If the binary file is really large then it’s better to load it as (char*) array if enough RAM is available via low level read function http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Reading-files-at-a-low-level.html
and then you can parse it.

But this will only help you to load large files, not to parse complex structures.

Not sure, but you could also take a look at yacc.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like yacc will be a solution, he isn't trying to parse the file, he wants to read binary formatted data to a data structure.

You can read the data in and then map it to a struct that matches the format.  If the data is complex you may need to lay structs over it in a variety of ways depending on how the data layout works.  So basically read the file into a char* or and then select the element where your struct starts, cast that element to a pointer to your stuct and then access the element.  Without more detail it's impossible to be more specific than this.